# why ng-model not Binding values within the textBox

Tags: angularjs

Here when i try to popup values in mode why value not binding in textbox but out side textBox  `{{emp.E_Name}}`its working fine

```
<form novalidate name="f1" ng-submit="SaveDb(emp)">
    <div class="col-sm-8">
      <input type="text" name="nam" class="form-control" data-modal="modal" ng-model="emp.E_Nam"  ng-class="Submitted?'ng-dirty':''" required autofocus />
             {{emp.E_Name}}
```

Comment: ooo thanks lot u find my mistake

Answer (score 0):

You got a typo `ng-model="emp.E_Nam"` should be `ng-model="emp.E_Name"`